# How to show the Non Blank value in Excel

Tags: excel, vlookup, lookup-tables

I have a certain Sheet example below, and I would like to get the non blank only.
Does excel has a certain code that will show the same below?

Result   ||  2/1      ||    2/2     ||  2/3      ||  2/4

Happy    || (blank)   ||  (blank) || (blank)     ||  Happy

Enjoy    || (blank)   ||  (blank) || Enjoy       ||  (blank)

Answer (score 0):

Use TEXTJOIN

```
=TEXTJOIN("", TRUE, A1:A4)
```

(The first value is the separator to use in the case that multiple non-blank entries are found.)

Comment: Hi, do we have alternative for TextJoin? It seems that my Excel version is not supporting the said.

Comment: You could use CONCAT or CONCATENATE, but those do not offer the option to specify a separator. e.g., `CONCAT(A1:A4)`